# difference between simulate and predict in lme4?

Tags: r, predict, lme4, mixed-models

What's the difference between "simulate" and "predict" in lme4 (or in general in mixed-effect models)?

lme4 documentation only says:

> Simulate: simulate responses from a "merMod" fitted model object.
>   Predict: a numeric vector of predicted values.

lme4 vignette says:

> The fitted method retrieves fitted values that are conditional on all
>   of the modes of the random effects; the predict method returns the
>   same values by default, but also allows for predictions to be made
>   conditional on different sets of random effects. For example, if the
>   re.form argument is set to NULL (the default), then the predictions
>   are conditional on all random effects in the model; if re.form is ~0
>   or NA, then the predictions are made at the population level (all
>   random effect values set to zero).

But it's still not clear for me.
Could anybody explain it with an equation or just better, please?

I guess one is the other plus a random error.

Comment: Old question, you certainly had found the answer. For those ending up here with search engines, the answer is given here: https://tmalsburg.github.io/predict-vs-simulate.html